# Extend ARPaymentEntry Release Action

Tags: acumatica

Hi I am trying to extend the ARPaymentEntry graph so I can do some extra stuff when the user releases the payment.

I have extended the paymententry graph and copied the Release action over like so

```
    public PXAction<ARPayment> release;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Release", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
    [PXProcessButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter)
    {

        PXCache cache = Base.Document.Cache;
        List<ARRegister> list = new List<ARRegister>();
        foreach (ARPayment ardoc in adapter.Get<ARPayment>())
        {
            if (!(bool)ardoc.Hold)
            {
                cache.Update(ardoc);
                list.Add(ardoc);
            }
        }
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new PXException(Messages.Document_Status_Invalid);
        }
        Base.Save.Press();

        PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate()
        {
            if (SyncPaymentToRex(list))
            {
                ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(list, false);
            }
        });

        return list;
    }
```

If you look at the PXLongOperation I have a my own method I want to pass before it goes and releases the document.

Now this works for me but there is no user feedback on the screen (e.g. the controls arent disabled, no processing icon appears while its performing the operation etc) and also the screen doesnt reload, I have to manually reload the page before I can see the payment has been release etc

Can I get some help so I can get the page updating and reacting like it usually does on release but with my code in there as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
     public PXAction<ARPayment> release;


  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Release", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
    [PXProcessButton]
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter)
    {

        PXCache cache = Base.Document.Cache;
        List<ARRegister> list = new List<ARRegister>();
        foreach (ARPayment ardoc in adapter.Get<ARPayment>())
        {
            if (!(bool)ardoc.Hold)
            {
                cache.Update(ardoc);
                list.Add(ardoc);
            }
        }
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new PXException(Messages.Document_Status_Invalid);
        }
        Base.Save.Press();

        PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this.Base, delegate()
        {
            if (SyncPaymentToRex(list))
            {
                ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(list, false);
            }
        });

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.

I updating a custom field in ARAdjust in my method, when it goes to release it I get a ARADJUST has been updated by another process any idea of how I get around that?

Comment: please give full code for betteru understanding. i think u have raised a new case for this.